# Adding keyboard shortcuts to nautilus 3.18.5

Tags: keyboard, nautilus, shortcuts

I'd like to know if there's a way to add keyboard shortcuts to nautilus (the version on this system is 3.18.5 and I'm running an updated Ubuntu 16.04.2 system).  Ideally I want the keyboard shortcut to activate an action that I've configured using the nautilus-actions extension of nautilus, but if that's not possible maybe someone can help me find out how I can modify or add keyboard shortcuts to nautilus.  Anyone know?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `System Settings`, and open the `keyboard panel`, and click on the shortcuts button/tab, and scroll down to custom shortcuts. Set your shortcut there.

Comment: Yes, but what I'm looking for is a nautilus specific shortcut so that it is possible to have access to the filename of the currently selected file.  The nautilus specific keyboard shortcut would either activate an action I defined using nautilus-actions or would run a script, passing the filename as the argument to the script.  See why I want it to be a shortcut specific to nautilus?

Comment: I had found that using the python-nautilus extension, it is possible to extend nautilus this way.  At this site]1] I found some information on this and some a script that I modified as is shown below, and tested it to see if nautilus recognized the keyboard shortcut, but it didn't work for me.  Maybe someone could enlighten me?

Comment: I can't show the modifications, but the shortcuts are not recognized.  The site I mentioned is: [1] http://zverovich.net/2011/02/18/user-defined-keyboard-shortcuts-in-nautilus.html

Comment: I believe that Nautilus was rewritten for 16.04? and I'm not sure that the script you link to will work any more.